# Validation of input data. Inside or outside a function, the optimal way

Tags: c, function, input, error-handling

Below is a function which converts a character representing a decimal digit into an integer which has the value of that digit.

```
#define CONVERSION_ERROR -1

int8_t char_to_int (char c)
{
    if ( c < '0' || c > '9' ) return CONVERSION_ERROR;
    return c - '0';
}
```

Design-wise, how practical it is to check the function input and return error code inside the function like the one above. Usually this type of a function will be used inside an expression where you won't check for the error codes but such a return value can mess your calculations in a quite unpredictable way. Sure, you could choose something convenient, say **0**, for the error code, but then it will interfere with the valid data.

On the other hand you can remove the input check from a function altogether and move it somewhere outside but by doing this you will probably make your function less self contained.

So I wonder where is that fine line between which checks to perform inside and which outside the function?

Comment: In your case `-1` will not interfere with valid data which is between 0 and 9.

Comment: You have to decide whether the errors matter.  If they matter, they must be handled by the calling code.  If they don't matter, why are you bothering with the validation in the first place?  If you design the function so it can return an error state (or detect an error state), you are saying "it matters".  So, calling code has to deal with the possibility of error.  If the data won't be in error, why are you checking?

Comment: Unless the input verification is a crucial part of your algorithm, I would remove the check altogether and simply ensure that I always use the function on valid characters.

Comment: You might consider the merits of `assert(isdigit((unsigned char)c));` in place of the `if` statement, or placed before the `if` statement.  That will tell you whether your debug testing ever spots a non-digit in the data.